# .append() element with more than one class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't find any info on whether or not it's possible to use .append() to append an element to html and give that element more than one class

```
 $( ".nav" ).append("<li class=tab><a href=#content class=menu-button>Menu</a></li>");
```

Will work just fine, but

```
$( ".nav" ).append("<li class=tab home-tab><a href=#content class=home-button>Home</a></li>");
```

Will not out put the correct html. The html captures the tab class but not the home-tab class.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: The HTML specification says: Attributes are placed inside the start tag, and consist of a name and a value, separated by an = character. The attribute value can remain unquoted if it doesn't contain spaces or any of " ' ` = < or > . Otherwise, it has to be quoted using either single or double quotes.

Comment: Learn about the syntax for attributes: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attributes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe using single quotes will work

```
$( ".nav" ).append("<li class='tab home-tab'><a href='#content' class='home-button'>Home</a></li>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the list of classes within single quotes, and you can use as many as desired. Example of what will work for multiple classes:

```
$( ".nav" ).append("<li class='tab home-tab'><a href='#content' class='home-button'>Home</a></li>");
```